# Variable Scope in C programming

Tags: c, scope

In c, when this block of code is run,it outputs 10 10 10 10 10. I think the loop should exit after 1st execution as i becomes 11 but it is not happening. Why it is so?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i; 
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
     int i=10;  
     printf("%d\t",i);
     i++;
  }
  return;
}
```

But when program is written as below the output is similar to what i am thinking(i.e.10 ).What is the exact difference between above code and the code shown below? How C is handling these variable? I would be glad if anyone explain about this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i; 
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
     i=10;  
     printf("%d\t",i);
     i++;
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't do `return;` from `main()` — it should have a value returned, and the compiler should be complaining.

Comment: That should be `return 0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first program, `for` loop is using the `i` declared outside the `for` to control the loop. The `printf` uses the `i` declared inside the `for` loop to print the value and this `i` has block scope.

The new declaration of `i` in the for `loop` temporarily hides the old declaration. Now the value of `i` is `10`. At the end of the `for` loop block the new `i` is not visible to the program and the variable regains its old meaning and this time `i` stores the value as per the iteration of loop (either `1`, `2`, `3` or `4`).

Comment: ...as for(), while() and most control structures, except switch ... case (which uses labels and not blocks) in C are separate scopes with the condition/control block being a _extra_ scope between the outer and inner scope. Thus variables defined in the control block are valid in the control block *and* the structure body.

Comment: @dom0: To be pedantic, the "inner scope" is not a special part of the control structure.  A control structure takes a statement, and in this case it happens to be a *block statement*.  A block statement creates a new scope.  It's no different to e.g. `int main(void) { int i; { int i; ... } }`.

Comment: So,new declaration inside the for loop hides the previous declaration of **i** and when control reaches to the update section of for loop, **i** declared inside the loop is hidden.? @haccks

Comment: @Kindle; Yes. Exactly.

Answer (score 3):

In the first code you declare your variable twice: one outside the loop and the second one inside the loop. So inside the loop compiler found another declaration for the variable so it uses the inner declaration (this called [block scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Block_scope)).

So that the first program print `10 10 10 10 10` because this is the inner declaration `int i=10`

But in the second code you declare it once so the compiler use this declaration in the whole program.

Answer (score 2):

In C99 or later, you can write this variation on your code with 3 independent variables called `i`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i = 19;
    printf("i0 = %d\n", i);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("i1 = %d\n", i);
        int i = 10;
        printf("i2 = %d\n", i);
        i++;
    }
    printf("i0 = %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
i0 = 19
i1 = 0
i2 = 10
i1 = 1
i2 = 10
i1 = 2
i2 = 10
i1 = 3
i2 = 10
i1 = 4
i2 = 10
i0 = 19
```

(In C89, you can't have the variable tagged `i1` in the output, and you couldn't demonstrate the two variables in the loop because declarations have to precede statements such as `printf()` calls.)

Answer (score 1):

Because in first example the `i` inside the loop is not the same as the one which governs/controls the loop, it is a completely different variable though with same name.